# Unhandled Promise Rejection TypeError B.setState is not a Function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to setState of a variable inside a class but it throws an error saying :

> "Unhandled Promise Rejection TypeError B.setState is not a Function"

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export default class B extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.message = this.message.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      value: '',
    };
  }

  static message = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('FromValue').then((FromValue) => {
      this.setState({ value: FromValue });
      console.log(this.state.value);
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to bind 'this'. What 'this' is referring to is the issue.

```
static message  =()=>{
  let self = this
  // Stuff
  self.setState()
```

Edit: also with promise chaining you need a .catch(error => handleError(error)) at the end of all your .then()s

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export default class ACHServicesMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //This binding of static method should also give you error
        this.message = this.message.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            value: '',
        };
    }

    //Static methods don't have access to this so it won't work
    static message = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.getItem('FromValue').then((FromValue) => {
            this.setState({ value: FromValue }, () => {
                console.log(this.state.value);
                //Here in callback you can get updated state value
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Use async and await for Promise based request. 
Also, if you have static method, you can not access this context and binding of static method should also give you error.

You can make that method normal and bind it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Krina !! But what else should i use in place of static. Because without static i got an error saying "_main.default.message is not a function"

Comment: Just make a normal method and call it using this.nameOfMethod or if you want it to be static only then call it using classname.methodname

Comment: I am trying calling message function from another class. It only work with static do you have any alternative to call that function without static

Answer (score 0):

Remove **static** keyword because you can not call the message method by this because it exposed as a static method function which you can just call it by using the original class referral name like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

export default class B extends Component {
  state = {
    value: ""
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.message = this.message.bind(this);
  }
  
  message() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("FromValue").then(FromValue => {
      this.setState({ value: FromValue }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.value);
      });
    });
  };
}
```

The static use case is just for defaultProps and propsType objects in each component.

Comment: But what else should i use in place of static. Because without static i got an error saying "_main.default.message is not a function"

Comment: Thanks for  your efforts Bro but i got the same error "message is not a function" when i tried calling it from another class like
onPress=()=>{
B.message()
}

Comment: You have no access to the message publicly. just you can use the message function locally in the B component.

Comment: How can i do it globally ?

Comment: pass data by prop if you wanna do it globally.